# When is improbability a proof of tampering?

Tags: probability

So, I just watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8TlTaTHgzo) of some guy being accused of cheating in a game (he tried to place a world record) and the argument boiled down to "this sequence of events is so astronomically improbable that we declare that you cheated".

Which is OK, fair point. However... it got me thinking. There are many ways that something can be really improbable. If I shuffle a full deck of 52 cards, the odds of THAT particular sequence are on the order of 1 in 8*10<sup>67</sup>. But just because I got it doesn't mean I cheated, and I don't think anyone would accuse me of it either.

Or, let's put it in a more abstract way. Let's take a dice roll. A standard, 6-sided dice. If you roll it 100 times and get a value of "6" in all of them, you'd probably be suspected of cheating because the odds of that happening are $\cfrac{1}{6^{100}}$. On the other hand, if you got the values 33535516343413352544 35425515536356234615 62256526346236661225 31422624135261426131 54445152412651245623, the odds of getting that sequence are also $\cfrac{1}{6^{100}}$. So why isn't this suspicious?

I feel like I'm missing something trivial.

Comment: The dice sequences can be measured for randomness in other ways, for example, the rough proportions of each value out of the total.  It may be more or less difficult to determine proper random chances based on the game conditions, but usually there is a way.

Comment: The Bayesian perspective:  if event X is extremely unlikely given that there's no cheating, but much more likely given that there's cheating, then it's evidence of cheating.  If X is equally unlikely whether there was cheating or not, then it's not evidence of cheating.  I would say rolling 100 sixes in a row falls into the first category, and rolling 3353551634 etc. falls into the second category.

Comment: Oh gosh I thought MSE would stay safe from the Dream drama...

Comment: @MichaelMorrow - Haha, I don't want any drama. In fact, I only heard about him yesterday and don't really care about the whole thing. I was just genuinely curious about the mathemathical side of the problem. I can remove the link and alter the question to avoid mentioning the scandal, if you think it would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** It comes down to *patterns* people perceive and the *number of configurations* that can be associated with those patterns. In the space of all possible configurations, configurations with a pattern comprise a small part of that space, and thus such a pattern is unlikely to occur randomly.

---

**Long answer:** You're right that any *specific* sequence of 100 die rolls is just as likely to be drawn as a sequence where a $6$ is drawn for each of those rolls. However, the fact that we could draw two sequences of the former type and-at a glance-be unlikely to distinguish between them suggests that our mind is unable to intuit any pattern or order that defines either specific sequence. In fact, our mind perceives both sequences as *random* as is evident in your case by the fact that you likely just wrote an unplanned sequence of digits, and if you were to write the question again you would just write another (likely different) unplanned sequence of digits. But if you were to repeatedly write this question, you would easily quote the 100 die rolls of $6$ each time.

This is to say that your mind perceives an order in the $100$ die rolls of a $6$ that is does not perceive in the *specific* and equally probable $100$ die rolls for a particular sequence. It perceives this specific sequence as random in much the same way that clothes thrown about a room have specific positions but appear randomly placed to an onlooker.

And so when it intuitively evaluates the probability of such a sequence, it is not asking "What is the probability that I get a $3$, then another $3$, then a $5$, then another $3$,...?" but instead asking "What is the probability that I get a random collection of numbers?" Conversely, with the $100$ rolls of a $6$, your mind does see a specific pattern thus asks "What is the probability that I get $100$ $6$s in a row?"

If we take $\Omega_A$ to be the number of $100$ die-roll sequences with any *random* number of $1$s, $2$s, $3$s, $4$s, $5$s, and $6$s, and $\Omega_B$ to be the number of 100 die-roll sequences with only $6$s, it is clear that $\Omega_A \gg \Omega_B$. Thus, with $\Omega_{\text{tot}}$ being the number of all such die-roll sequences, it is also clear that the probability of a random sequence $p_A = \Omega_A/ \Omega_{\text{tot}}$ is much greater than that for the "only $6$s" sequence $p_B = \Omega_B/ \Omega_{\text{tot}}$.

---

**Dream drama:** I don't know anything about the "Dream drama" mentioned in an above comment, but if someone was accused of cheating due to there apparently being a low probability of *something*, it would be because this *something* is associated with a pattern that the accusers can perceive and such a pattern is unlikely in the space of possible configurations of what they are observing.

Comment: You're basically right, however that still doesn't answer the question "is this enough of a proof of cheating?" Because it seems pretty subjective. Maybe math.se isn't the right place for that question, I don't know.

Comment: The question "Is this enough proof of cheating?" is an epistemic question in that it concerns how people determine what they do or do not count as knowledge. In particular, establishing that there is "enough proof" must be done inductively rather than deductively and thus can't be answered through a derivation. The definition of randomness and people's subjective interpretation of randomness is still key here because patterns that are incorporated as knowledge exist as directly opposed to randomness and people must inductively decide the limit of the unlikelihood of the pattern....(continued)

Comment: ...for its existence to be counted as knowledge. When CERN physicists discover a new particle, they also ask themselves "is the data we have enough proof of a new discovery?" and they have decided on a limit of "5 sigma" for discovery, meaning that if what they see has a likelihood of $3\times 10^{-7}$ chance of occurring randomly then, it *most likely* didn't occur randomly and we can count it as some pattern in the world. Social scientists have had less stringent limits which have led to epistemic problems in their field. So "enough proof" is always subjective.